# How to obtain the key agreement algorithm used in TLS 1.3 handshake using OpenSSL API?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, cryptography

I was modifying the example client code given on the OpenSSL [s_client page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) to understand a few functions. I added the following lines after the chain verification part :

```
const SSL_CIPHER* curr_cipher = SSL_get_current_cipher(ssl);
printf("SSL_CIPHER_standard_name: %s\n", SSL_CIPHER_standard_name(curr_cipher));
printf("SSL_get_cipher_version: %s\n", SSL_get_cipher_version(ssl));
int kx_nid = SSL_CIPHER_get_kx_nid(curr_cipher);
printf("SSL_CIPHER_get_kx_nid: %d\n", kx_nid);
printf("OBJ_nid2ln(%d): %s\n", kx_nid, OBJ_nid2ln(kx_nid));
printf("SSL_CIPHER_description: %s\n", SSL_CIPHER_description(curr_cipher, NULL, 0));
```

Instead of getting the key exchange algorithm used, I got the following output after connecting to random.org using TLS 1.3 :

```
SSL_CIPHER_standard_name: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
SSL_get_cipher_version: TLSv1.3
SSL_CIPHER_get_kx_nid: 1063
OBJ_nid2ln(1063): kx-any
SSL_CIPHER_description: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384  TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
```

The man page for `SSL_CIPHER_get_kx_nid` says it returns `NID_kx_any` for TLS 1.3. How can I programatically get the actual key agreement (`NID_kx_ecdhe`) and authentication protocol (`NID_auth_rsa`) used in the handshake from the `SSL` object?

Comment: You're obtaining the generic characteristics of the `SSL_CIPHER` type, not what was actually used in your SSL connection. You're seeing, "If you use this cipher, these Kx and Au protocols could be used". You want the protocols that were actually used in the SSL connection.  I'd think you'd need to use one of the `SSL_get...()` functions instead to get the properties of the connection itself, but which one is not readily apparent.